# How do I tell which version of monotouch I have installed?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

How do I tell which version of monotouch I have installed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's several ways to get the version number.

From the terminal you can do:

```
$ /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch --version
mtouch 5.3.5.1340204820
```

or

```
$ cat /Developer/MonoTouch/Version 
5.3.5
```

Also from MonoDevelop you can do **About MonoDevelop** then select **Version Information** and this will give you (a lot of data, including MonoTouch version)

```
...
Monotouch: 5.3.5
...
```

Comment: Curious : you have version 5.3.5 whereas I only have 5.2.12, yet I downloaded the latest FULL version. Can I get a newer version?

Comment: 5.2.x are the current **stable** versions, 5.2.12 being the latest of them. You can set MonoDevelop (**Check for Updates** menu) to look for **beta** and **alpha** releases, that will show you the *unstable* builds, 5.3.x at this time.

Comment: from MonoDevelop you can do About MonoDevelop then select Version Information and this will give you (a lot of data, including MonoTouch version)

Comment: As a warning, though, going to "Add-in Manager", expanding "Mobile Development", and selecting "Mono iPhone development" will get you a version that has nothing to do with your MonoTouch version (e.g., on my machine, MonoTouch reports v6.0.8 but "Mono iPhone development" reports v3.1.1).