# Binded MonoTouch.Dialog from Git works different than MonoTouch.Dialog from Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios, storyboard, .net-assembly, monotouch.dialog

Because of writing some specific Dialog Elements, i uses the source of MonoTouch.Dialog (current version). BTW. In my Project i use DialogViewController in some Storyboard Views.
Now i have recognized a problem:
The following code works perfect with binded assembly of MonoTouch.Dialog, but if i use the Source-Version of MonoTouch.Dialog the UIAlertView does not appear on taping the Accessory-Button...

```
var sse = new StyledStringElement ("DetailDisclosureIndicator") { Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DetailDisclosureButton };
                    sse.AccessoryTapped += delegate {
                        var alert = new UIAlertView ("Accessory", "Accessory clicked!", null, "Ok");                alert.Show ();

RootElement root = new RootElement ("test") {
                    new Section (""){
                        sse, 
                        new BooleanImageElement ("test1", false, checkedImage, uncheckedImage),
                    }};

_dvc = new DialogViewController(root);
_navc = new UINavigationController (_dvc);
this.View.AddSubview (_navc.View);
```

What do i wrong? Why works this code only with the Xamarin Assembly of MT.D ?

Answer (score 0):

> What do i wrong?

Likely nothing...

> Why works this code only with the Xamarin Assembly of MT.D ?

MonoTouch.Dialog from GIT is the latest (bleeding edge) version available. There's not hidden version of MonoTouch.Dialog ;-)

Each new release of MonoTouch brings a specific (nearly the most recent / well tested) version of MonoTouch.Dialog when it ships.

You'll get new features faster using GIT - but you might also be the first to spot new bugs or regressions.

Please report any change of behaviour to http://bugzilla.xamarin.com and include which version of MonoTouch (e.g. 5.2.12) and which GIT revision you use (e.g. things like *current version* might be different when you question is being read than when it was written).

Comment: Thanks for your hint. But i'm sorry i cant find the assembly version of MonoTouch. All Assembly DLL's of MonoTouch are marked with Assembly Version 0.0.0.0. Only the System Assemblies have "correct" Version-Numbers 2.0.5.0.
The Path of MonoTouch uses some kind of Version /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/...

Comment: For assemblies shipping with MonoTouch providing the version of MonoTouch being used is enough, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11492989/220643

Answer (score 0):

Now I am a little surprised, but still a loss.
The Sample packed to MonoTouch.Dialog GIT version works fine. Specifically the code in DemoStyle.cs (the same DetailDisclosureIndicator situation with var sse).
The sample works with both kinds of assemblies. 
The differences to my app are:
1) my app is ipad-app
2) my UINavigationController is part of a UIView that is part of a Storyboard.

Two Minutes and one Test later.
The main reason why the AccessorButton do not work in my Storyboard iPad App is the methode AccessoryButtonTapped in the class Source (part of DialogViewController.cs).
If i debug my App this Methode will be not called, if i tap on the accessor button. 
If i debug the iphone Sample (added to MonoTouch.Dialog source) the AccessoryButtonTapped methode of the class Source will be called and my breakpoint in AccessoryButtonTapped will be reached...